# OpenSocial for facebook and twitter

Tags: facebook, api, twitter, opensocial

I am assigned to make a research on using of Open social but stuck on the decision to continue because of facebook and twitter.
Does anybody know if the two gigantic social networking sites (facebook and twitter) implemented open social? Do they do implement it? If no, can someone tell me why otherwise if yes, can someone teach me how and give some samples? Thanks guys.

P.S. This link: http://docs.opensocial.org/display/OSD/List+of+OpenSocial+Containers , there's no twitter and facebook on the containers list. Does this mean fb and twitter does not support open social?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. OpenSocial is a competitor of the Facebook platform. However, there once existed a project (OpenSocket) to integrate OpenSocial in the Facebook platform. Though I don't know the status of it any longer. Their web site is highly outdated and is warned to contain malware.

Comment: thanks aron.. does it mean twitter also does not implement it ?

Comment: yes, it does. Twitter does not implement opensocial. Btw, Google, OpenSocials biggest player and promoter, has dropped its support of OpenSocial. Likely, they are working on expanding their own Google+ platform API as of now.

Comment: @Aron Google dropped support for OpenSocial? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @martijno, oops. Sorry. I may have spread misinformation there. They have closed down Social Graph API. They still seem to be behind OpenSocial, at least for now.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, they do not implement OpenSocial for obvious reasons. Both recognize the power they can leverage with their social graph. If you want to use their data, you should look into their APIs